# Google Static Maps With Traffic and Public Transport Overlays

Tags: c#, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-static-api

I use the following to get a png image of the location I want:

```
string.Format(
            "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center={0},{1}&zoom={2}&size={3}x{4}&maptype={5}&sensor=false",
            latitude,
            longitude,
            zoomLevel,
            width,
            height,
            (char)this.Type);
```

How can I add traffic or public transport overlays to the image via the URL? Is there an alternative URL api?

Comment: vote for it at https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35817019

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Appending the following, for example for traffic overlay;

> &layer=t

For other overlays just use the link button in the top right of the bottom left hand pane after selecting the layer you want to see which parameters need to be added to the URL to show the given overlay(s)

Comment: Ah, didin't spot the api part does that mean you cannot use the above idea?

Comment: That works in the browser whan you go to googles site but not using their static map api.

Comment: isn't it a little bit lame that Google still doesn't support this in their static maps? ... Bing does... :/